Ruby nested blocks call sequence
I have a very specific case and little bit confused about how and most important why methods inside nested blocks called like this
This is simplified example of methods what called:
class Foo
  def meth(content = nil, **kwargs, &block)
    p 'content: '
    p content
    p 'kwargs: '
    p kwargs
    p 'block: '
    p block

    if content
      proc { content }.call
    elsif block_given?
      yield
    end
  end

  def meth_block
    meth attr: 'fourth' do
      'Hello'
    end 
  end

  def run
    meth attr: 'first' do 
      meth attr: 'second' do
        meth(meth_block, attr: 'third')
      end
    end
  end
end

meth should accept both positional args and block values as attributes and it works pretty well except this specific case what I described in run method
After calling Foo.new.run I get following result:
Foo.new.run
"content: "
nil
"kwargs: "
{:attr=>"first"}
"block: "
#<Proc:0x000000011c6ec720 (pry):24>
"content: "
nil
"kwargs: "
{:attr=>"second"}
"block: "
#<Proc:0x000000011c6ec220 (pry):25>
"content: "
nil
"kwargs: "
{:attr=>"fourth"}
"block: "
#<Proc:0x000000011c6ebf28 (pry):18>
"content: "
"Hello"
"kwargs: "
{:attr=>"third"}
"block: "
nil
=> "Hello"

As you can see meth_block called before meth(attr: 'third') at first it call block inside and than meth(attr: 'third') without any arguments at all
Is there a way to change this sequence control it?
Maybe someone can describe for me how this structure actually works.
Thanks a lot.

I don't understand your code's intent. What is the expected result and what are you trying to achieve?

BTW, proc { content }.call is equivalent to content. Wrapping content in a proc and calling it right away doesn't do anything.

At no point does it call "meth(attr: 'third') without any arguments at all". It calls meth("Hello", attr: 'third'). Is the confusion on why it would call meth_block first? How else would it know what the first argument in meth(meth_block, attr: 'third') is other than to determine the result of calling meth_block? Please clarify the question.

I think you're expecting meth(meth_block, attr: 'third') to pass in a reference to meth_block and then meth calls meth_block.
Instead, meth_block is called immediately and its return value is passed to meth.
This:
meth(meth_block, attr: 'third')

Is the same as this:
meth(self.meth_block(), attr: 'third')


meth_block is executed

meth attr: 'fourth' { 'Hello' } is executed.
It returns "Hello"


meth_block returns "Hello".
"Hello" is passed to meth.

Resulting in this call:
meth("Hello", attr: 'third')

As pointed out in the comments, proc { content }.call is simply content.

What I think you intend is this:
class Foo
  def meth(method = nil, **kwargs, &block)
    # Similar, but more concise. `p foo` is basically `puts foo.inspect`.
    # https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.4/Kernel.html#method-i-p
    puts "method: #{method.inspect}"
    puts "kwargs: #{kwargs.inspect}"
    puts "block: #{block.inspect}"

    # We take a Method object (really anything that responds to call)
    if method
      # And call it.
      method.call
    elsif block_given?
      yield
    end
  end

  def meth_block
    meth attr: 'fourth' do
      'Hello'
    end 
  end

  def run
    meth attr: 'first' do 
      meth attr: 'second' do
        # Send a Method object wrapping `self.meth_block` to be called later.
        meth(self.method(:meth_block), attr: 'third')
      end
    end
  end
end

p Foo.new.run

The change is to use #method to obtain a Method object for #meth_block. That Method object is passed into meth and then executed with method.call.

From a practical perspective, the complicated arguments are not necessary. Instead, use your existing blocks.
class Foo
  def meth(**kwargs, &block)
    puts "kwargs: #{kwargs.inspect}"
    puts "block: #{block.inspect}"

    yield if block_given?
  end

  def meth_block
    meth attr: 'fourth' do
      'Hello'
    end 
  end

  def run
    meth attr: 'first' do 
      meth attr: 'second' do
        meth attr: 'third' do 
          meth_block
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

p Foo.new.run


In your last example, you could also pass the method's Method object via meth attr: 'third', &method(:meth_block)
